# double quotes in mysql data not working for json

Tags: php, json

I have code like

```
    $m_strOutput= "{\"success\":true,\"results\":" . $m_objQuery->num_rows() . ",\"rows\":";
    $m_strOutput = $m_strOutput . json_encode($m_objQuery->result());
    $m_strOutput = $m_strOutput . "}";
```

But some data already has double quotes in it. So it breaks my views where i try to parse it. How do i solve this double quotes problem.

Comment: Don't manually cobble together JSON. Make an array which you encode all together using `json_encode`.

Comment: maybe you could try addslashes for that data?

Comment: Maybe you need to replace the single quotes?

Comment: I couldn't quite read the code. What does $m_ojbQuery->result() return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. This is not a problem of double quote. You'll have syntax error to put a value into a JSON object without a key.
2. You should let json_encode do all the jobs for you.

Codes that might fit your case:

```
<?php

$m_strArr = array(
  'success' => true,
  'results' => $m_objQuery->num_rows(),
  'rows' => $m_objQuery->result(),
);

$m_strOutput = json_encode($m_strArr);
?>
```

Comment: i get same old error like "uncaught exception: Invalid JSON:"

Comment: This is odd. Can you show us an example of the JSON output (that leads to the error)?